# what's the php way of setting the lang of a document?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Recently I've learned that setting the charset using the meta tag is a pretty *sub-standard* way of doing things since we should instead set the charset in the server side like this:

```
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
```

Does this **concept** also applies to the lang attribute of the html tag?

If so, what's the php way of setting the lang attribute of a document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Content-Language](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.12) header.

Comment: Also stick with the proper language codes per http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/dirlang.html#h-8.1.1

Comment: so basically just like the meta charset, if i set the content-language header i can safely omit setting it within the html itself right?

Comment: @Richet: read [this document](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-http-and-lang).

Answer (score 0):

Same as the regular HTML way: no difference for php. `<html lang="en">` remains the way forward.

Comment: what do you mean remains the way forward?

Comment: Sorry: I meant **continue to use the standard `lang` attribute**